# Angular 4 + AOT webpack build issue

Tags: angular, webpack, angular2-aot

I'm using Angular 4 and building project with webpack and AoT, but it's giving me this error:

```
ERROR in ng:///D:/proj/src/client/app/app.component.html (14,5): '$event' is declared but never used.
```

I'd made simplified project copy in plunker: http://embed.plnkr.co/RxY2mhfhJmcBFKjG70f0/

You can reproduce this issue with following steps:

1. Download project from the plunker: https://plnkr.co/edit/RxY2mhfhJmcBFKjG70f0?p=info
2. In project root `npm i` then `npm run build:client` or `npm run build-v:client`

If you change the `src/client/app/app.component.html` at line 13 like this:

```
<li *ngFor="let hero of heroes" (click)="onSelect(hero, $event)" [class.selected]="hero === selectedHero">
```

the error will disappear. But this is a bad solution obviously.

Any ideas to solve the problem?

I think that AoT somehow compiles the template to some kind of intermediate resource where it adds that variable. But I can't find out how to manage/prevent/fix this.

Comment: Apparently you have an `$event` defined somewhere and it is not being used.. but I don't see this in your plnkr. Are you sure you put the right code there? The error implies something like `<div (foo)="$event"></div>` in your HTML.

Comment: @Lansana, I updated my question to explain yours

Comment: I'm pretty sure this has to do with the compiler/build process being used. There is an `$event` created for the `(click)`, however you do not use it. That is similar to declaring a variable in your typescript and not using it. I think the compiler or build process you're using throws an error in this case, and it can be proven because if you use the `$event` the error goes away. Did you create your own custom webpack build config, or are you using the Angular CLI?

Comment: @Lansana, yes, I'm using custom webpack config, but this config is in the provided project as well. What is wrong with it? It looks quite common

Comment: Well there is not anything wrong with it per se, but the problem is Angular development continues on every day and the webpack config you have does not stay up to date with it. This is why you get that compilation error. With Angular CLI, you won't see this error because under the hood they make it optional to use the `$event` and don't throw any errors. With your custom webpack config, this error is caught because I assume your TD compiler will yell at any variables that are declared and not used, just like the error says.

Comment: Yes, sorry, typo. I meant TS for TypeScript.

Comment: At the very least, look for a flag in your configuration that allows you to declare variables without using them. That should solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in `src/client/tsconfig-aot.json`. The `"noUnusedParameters": true,` should be removed.

Thanks for help with comments. It took me to the right direction.

Comment: Glad I could help.